# How to redirect call to API from particular proxy server?

Tags: c#, proxy, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an API which i want to get access from one of my proxy server only. As that server have given all access to access that particular API. So I have single endpoint.

I have proxy server URL and Port and i want to add proxy settings in my app settings file and implement it so when call is given to API, that particular call pass through the Proxy server.

Please assist me how can I achieve this?

Current Call to API as below.

```
                            PushMessageAndroidRequest req = new PushMessageAndroidRequest();
                            req.registration_ids = list.Select(x => x.Token).ToList();
                            req.data = new AndroidData() { Payload = CommonLib.ConvertObjectToJson(payload) };

                            response = await RequestHandler.PostDataAsync<PushMessageResponse>(_appConfig.pushMessageConfigs.Url, req, new List<KeyValue>() { new KeyValue("Authorization", "key=" + _appConfig.pushMessageConfigs.Key) });
```

Sample code have written

```
 public static async Task<ResJsonOutput> ProxyDataAsync(string ApiPath,string obj, List<KeyValue> Headers = null)
        {
            ResJsonOutput result = new ResJsonOutput();
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            var requestUri = string.Format(ApiPath);
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);

                WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy(Settings.ProxyAddress, Settings.ProxyPort);
                myproxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
                request.Proxy = myproxy;

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    //JObject jResponse = JObject.Parse(stream.ReadToEnd());
                    //var isSuccess = jResponse.Value<bool>("success");
                    //result = (isSuccess) ? true : false;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```